# What does it mean when an object has multiple inputs?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, ssis, workflow, dataflow

I am a beginner at SSIS, and I am documenting and analyzing a control and data flow for a project. I am currently stumped by this part:

[image]

In which order are these flows fired off? Does it occur exactly as shown? For example when the process on the right is done (import pricelistitemdetail) then it starts Import Opportunity, and whenever import alternate add... completes then once again it will start import opportunity?

Effectively Import Opportunity will be executed twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The green lines have meaning too.  If that is a do the next step when the last is successful, it will wait for both inputs to finish before it starts.  Import Opportunity is only executed once.

You can watch it as it moves through the steps, and see how it flows.